# How to save specific data from response data to csv file

Tags: jmeter

In my webservices test plan, I am sending SOAP request to create user and it sends back username and unique id in the response data. I want to save that username and uniqueid into a CSV file.

Could anyone let me know how can I achieve that?

Comment: use an xpath or regex extractor to extract a value and then use a simple file writer to write out values to file

Comment: @RaGe Simple data writer won't be able to write extracted variables into a file. He needs to use beanshell postprocessor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract data using Regex post processor and save it to a variable.

Simple data writer, Flexible data writer, Save results to a file all these can write predefined variables, responses to a file in a fixed or little bit customizable format but won't let you write your custom variables.

For writing it to a file you need to use Beanshell processor.
Sample code would be,

```
username = vars.get("username");
password = vars.get("password");

f = new FileOutputStream("/path/user_details.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(username + "," + password);
f.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Nachiket.How can i save both values into a same column like username,password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sample_variables` property to store custom variables values into .jtl results file.

Add the following line to *user.properties* file (it lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sample_variables=username,password
```

You will see variables values within .jtl results file upon execution.

See [Default Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults) chapter for explanation and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties and ways of setting and/or overriding them.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for save a number to a csv:
thanks Nachiket Kate.

---

```
folio = vars.get("folioGuardado");    
f = new FileOutputStream("C:/GuardFolios/folios.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(folio);
f.close();
```