# Is it possible to replace variable in csv file

Tags: jmeter

The first request should create one object with id. This id I should replace "variableID_" in csv file:

{ "Id": variableID_, "Name": "Mary"}

in the next request.

Is it possible? And how I can do it? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the classic approach of RegexExtractor + BeanShell fusion?
Sth like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173107/how-to-save-specific-data-from-response-data-to-csv-file

Comment: I am trying something like this:
vars.get("${thisIsJson}").replace("variableID_","${newId}").

But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

vars.put("thisJsonFronCSV", vars.get("thisJsonFronCSV").replaceAll("variableID_","${new_id}"));